# Sphinx or mysql on joined tables

Tags: mysql, join, indexing, sphinx

I have several tables in my database which would require huge number of joins for the queries involved and tables will get updated frequently. There are different sets of questions I want to ask related to transitioning from mysql search to sphinx search.

I'm trying to use Sphinx to carry out the queries(not full text searches) as mysql engine is too slow because of huge number of joins involved.

So my first question is whether it makes sense to use sphinx for non-full-text searches by converting the fields into text through concatenation?

If the suggestion is to use sphinx, how do I use it to execute complex queries across all of these tables. I researched a lot and came up with these three alternatives and would like your views on which would be optimal.

1. Since Sphinx doesn't have JOINs, de-normalize all the tables into one table(or view) and then run the sphinx indexer on that. This seems to be the most inefficient way as it would result in billions of rows and also the other queries that doesn’t involve joining all the tables would be seriously hampered.
2. Create sphinx index on each of the tables separately. But this would not allow me to use these indexes for a query requiring joins across the tables. To overcome this, use sql_joined_field on the columns to be joined and sphinx will carry out the join process.
3. Put the JOIN in the sql_query that builds the index. The tables remain normalized, but you de-normalize when building the index. This seems to be a good solution. But there are going to be many updates/deletion/insertion on the parent tables. So is it going to be a tricky or tedious business to update the spinx indexes accordingly and will that hampers the performance in the long run after too many updates? How can one take care of the updates in parent tables and modify the sphinx indexes efficiently.

I would like to know what is a better way to proceed for addressing the issue. Sorry for the long question, but I wanted to aggregate my research so that same thing doesn't get repeated in the answers to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I would recommend 3.

Read about main+delta updates for a way to get updates quickly indexed (without having to rebuild the whole index)

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#delta-updates

Comment: thanx for your suggestion. I have a doubt though. From what it seems, delta updates seem to be for index derived from one table and not for the one derived from joins across multiple tables. Can the technique be utilized for the kind of problem I am dealing with?

Comment: Yes, not reason why not. I use delta indexing with a join across 4 tables. The 'filter' using the counter table, should (not must) filter the first table in the list, but it can join other tables just fine.